# Can the GC Matchmaking inviter receive a "declined" message?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

I'm developing an iOS game with multiplayer matches using Game Center.

A match is essentially a duel (2 players).

When one player sends an invitation to a friend, the friend's iPhone gets a banner on top of the screen. If you tap that banner, the game launches.

My invitation handler will display a confirmation menu: it asks if you want to leave the current session and start a duel with your friend.

Of course, you can say no. You can decline the match.

But as far as I'm concerned, **the inviter will remain stuck waiting for their friend to connect**.

Is it possible for the invitee to send back a message saying "declined" so that the inviter's matchmaking screen will stop waiting for the match?

I am using the default matchmaking view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way that you will be informed that an invitee "declined" the invitation. In fact, the inviter will be stuck in the same situation if the invitee doesn't click on the banner (just ignores it). The inviter will be waiting indefinitely.

Perhaps you should consider timing out / cancelling the invitation from the inviter after a particular period of time has elapsed. Since there is only one other player, it is reasonable to cancel an invite if the other player doesn't respond. Since the inviter is "inviting" the invitee, chances are that he can contact the invitee through some other means if he really wants to prod the invitee.

EDIT: In the case of "alerts" (this is only if the invitee has notifications to appear as alerts), the inviter will be informed that the invitation was declined, if the invitee clicked on "decline". But the same problem exists - if the invitee ignores the alert, the inviter will wait indefinitely. Also, your listener / invite handler will get triggered only after he accepts the invitation.

EDIT: Rather than show your own confirmation screen (asking the player if he wants to end the current session), you should assume that accepting the invite is intended to end the current session. If there is a single player mode of your game available, then you should save enough state to resume single player next time (if you want that feature). In the case of multiplayer, it is obvious that if a player accepts some other invitation that he won't mind ending the current session, unless it is a "turn based" game.